# This LinearLayout layout or its FrameLayout parent is useless

Tags: android, android-linearlayout

I'm new at this. 
Help me resolve this warning.
Thanks.

```
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" 
        android:layout_marginLeft="6dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="6dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="4dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="4dp"
        android:padding="0dp"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:background="@drawable/background_card">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/txtProductDescription"
        android:layout_marginTop="4dp"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:padding="6dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text=""
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
        android:fontFamily="sans-serif-light"/>

<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/RelativeLayout3"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="4dp"
    android:background="#40AF40"
    android:padding="6dp" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/txtOfferBig"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"   
</LinearLayout>
```

How can I fix the following error?

> warning:Consider replacing android:layout_toRightOf with
>   android:layout_toEndOf="@id/txtOfferBig" to better support
>   right-to-left layouts

Answer (score 0):

If they are simple warnings then don't mind then. They will not effect your build.

Answer (score 0):

This happens if you have a Layout that has only one child, maybe the child is really useless, in this case, if you want use layout constraints from the child you delete the parent, otherwise keep the parent.